# ruby-debug-ide fails to install on Ubuntu with Ruby 2.0

Tags: ruby, rubygems

I'm not sure why, but I had no issues installed ruby-debug-ide for the past several months in my Ubuntu VM (running with Vagrant/Virtualbox). Today, I did a `vagrant destroy` then a `vagrant up` and all of a sudden I'm getting this new issue.

All other developers with similar issues & solutions have not given me any solutions that work for my installation. I don't know what to do at this point. Help please!

```
almsgive@almsgive-box:~$ gem install ruby-debug-ide
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing ruby-debug-ide:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby mkrf_conf.rb
Installing base gem
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for vm_core.h... no
checking for vm_core.h... no
Makefile creation failed
**************************************************************************
No source for ruby-2.0.0-p576 provided with debugger-ruby_core_source gem.
**************************************************************************
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/bin/ruby
        --with-ruby-dir
        --without-ruby-dir
        --with-ruby-include
        --without-ruby-include=${ruby-dir}/include
        --with-ruby-lib
        --without-ruby-lib=${ruby-dir}/

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/debase-0.0.9 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/debase-0.0.9/gem_make.out
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:38:in `block in build'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:677:in `build_extensions'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:232:in `install'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:142:in `block in install'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:126:in `each'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/request_set.rb:126:in `install'
  /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p576/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/dependency_installer.rb:389:in `install'
  mkrf_conf.rb:34:in `rescue in <main>'
  mkrf_conf.rb:27:in `<main>'

rake failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p576/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0/ruby-debug-ide-0.4.22/gem_make.out
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem today with debugger-ruby_core_source (by way of debugger, not ruby-debug-ide). I changed my ruby version back to 2.0.0-p481. After that debugger-ruby_core_source installed as expected.

Comment: Just had the same problem, looks like 2.0.0-p576 isn't ready for prime time. I uninstalled and things started working again.